# Returning next line of file in C

Tags: c, malloc, free

I'm working on a project in `C`. The purpose of the project is to code a function that returns the next line of a file every time it's called.

I'm only allowed to use the `malloc`, `free` and `read` functions.

**Code I have Tried**

```c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "get_next_line.h"

int my_putstr(char *str)
{
    int i;

    if (str == NULL)
        return (1);

    i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        write(1, &str[i], 1);
        i = i + 1;
    }
    return (0);
}

char *my_strcpy(char *src, char *dest)
{
    int i;
    int r;

    r = 0;
    i = 0;

    if (src == NULL)
        return (dest);

    while (dest != NULL && dest[i] != '\0')
        i = i + 1;

    while (src[r] != '\0')
    {
        dest[i] = src[r];
        i = i + 1;
        r = r + 1;
    }
    dest[i] = '\0';
    return (dest);
}

int check_back_n(t_stock *stock)
{
    int i;

    if (stock->save == NULL)
        return (1);

    i = 0;
    while (stock->save[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (stock->save[i] == '\n')
            return (0);
        i = i + 1;
    }
    return (1);
}

int my_realloc(t_stock *stock)
{
    if ((stock->temp = malloc(sizeof(char) *
                (READ_SIZE * stock->counter) + 1)) == NULL)
        return (1);

    stock->temp = my_strcpy(stock->save, stock->temp);
    free(stock->save);

    if ((stock->save = malloc(sizeof(char) *
               (READ_SIZE * (stock->counter + 1)) + 1)) == NULL)
        return (1);

    stock->save = my_strcpy(stock->temp, stock->save);
    free(stock->temp);
    return (0);
}

char *fill_over(t_stock *stock, char *over)
{
    stock->r = 0;
    stock->i = 0;

    while (stock->save[stock->i] != '\n')
        stock->i = stock->i + 1;

    stock->save[stock->i] = '\0';
    stock->i = stock->i + 1;

    if ((over = malloc(sizeof(char) * READ_SIZE) + 1) == NULL)
        return (NULL);

    while (stock->save[stock->i] != '\0')
    {
        stock->save[stock->i] = over[stock->r];
        stock->save[stock->i] = '\0';
        stock->i = stock->i + 1;
        stock->r = stock->r + 1;
    }
    return (over);
}

char *get_next_line(const int fd)
{
    t_stock stock;
    static char *over;

    stock.counter = 2;
    if ((stock.save = malloc(sizeof(char) * READ_SIZE) + 1) == NULL)
        return (NULL);

    stock.save = my_strcpy(over, stock.save);
    free(over);
    while (check_back_n(&stock) == 1)
    {
        if (my_realloc(&stock) == 1)
            return (NULL);

        if ((stock.buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * READ_SIZE) + 1) == NULL)
            return (NULL);

        if ((stock.read_return = read(fd, stock.buffer, READ_SIZE)) == -1 ||
                        (stock.read_return == 0))
            return (stock.save);

        stock.counter = stock.counter + 1;
        stock.save = my_strcpy(stock.buffer, stock.save);
        free(stock.buffer);
    }
    if ((over = fill_over(&stock, over)) == NULL)
        return (NULL);

    return (stock.save);
}

int main()
{
    char *s;
    int fd;

    fd = open("test", O_RDONLY);
    while (s = get_next_line(fd))
    {
        my_putstr(s);
        write(1, "\n", 1);
        free(s);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

When I tried to run the code, I got the following errors:

```
*** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000002024031 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7283f)[0x7fbb5b3f383f]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x780ae)[0x7fbb5b3f90ae]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x78db6)[0x7fbb5b3f9db6]
./a.out[0x400a38]
./a.out[0x400ab4]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7fbb5b3a2b05]
./a.out[0x4005c9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 3146955                                /home/degana_r/rendu/CProgElem/GetNextLine/CPE_2015_getnextline/a.out
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 08:07 3146955                                /home/degana_r/rendu/CProgElem/GetNextLine/CPE_2015_getnextline/a.out
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:07 3146955                                /home/degana_r/rendu/CProgElem/GetNextLine/CPE_2015_getnextline/a.out
02024000-02045000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                      [heap]
7fbb5b16a000-7fbb5b180000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 157433                         /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
7fbb5b180000-7fbb5b37f000 ---p 00016000 08:05 157433                         /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
7fbb5b37f000-7fbb5b380000 r--p 00015000 08:05 157433                         /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
7fbb5b380000-7fbb5b381000 rw-p 00016000 08:05 157433                         /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
7fbb5b381000-7fbb5b51f000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 147837                         /lib64/libc-2.19.so
7fbb5b51f000-7fbb5b71e000 ---p 0019e000 08:05 147837                         /lib64/libc-2.19.so
7fbb5b71e000-7fbb5b722000 r--p 0019d000 08:05 147837                         /lib64/libc-2.19.so
7fbb5b722000-7fbb5b724000 rw-p 001a1000 08:05 147837                         /lib64/libc-2.19.so
7fbb5b724000-7fbb5b728000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fbb5b728000-7fbb5b748000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 162636                         /lib64/ld-2.19.so
7fbb5b91e000-7fbb5b921000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fbb5b946000-7fbb5b948000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fbb5b948000-7fbb5b949000 r--p 00020000 08:05 162636                         /lib64/ld-2.19.so
7fbb5b949000-7fbb5b94a000 rw-p 00021000 08:05 162636                         /lib64/ld-2.19.so
7fbb5b94a000-7fbb5b94b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffc76b9d000-7ffc76bbe000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                              [stack]
7ffc76be8000-7ffc76bea000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                              [vdso]
7ffc76bea000-7ffc76bec000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                              [vvar]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                      [vsyscall]
Aborted
```

Comment: And what debugging have you already done on your own?

Comment: i've already got rid of 2 free calls (free(stock.buffer) in get_next_line and free(stock->save) in my_realloc). This allowed me to make the function get_next_line work once, but when I call it multiples times, it gives me the error I linked

Comment: Firstly, please put the error into the question as text and not as an image. Secondly, getting rid of `free` calls is almost certainly not the right way to fix your problem as it will lead to memory leaks. But it doesn't sound like you have exhausted all your debugging options. How about building the code with debugging enabled (`-g`) to get better error output? How about running your program in a debugger or using debug print statements to show all the pointer values being allocated and freed? How about running [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to help you find the error?

Comment: we actually know how to debug a program. Explicitly, we would like to know why in some cases we can't free memory we allocated dynamically...

Comment: How do you know it is memory that you allocated (since there is no evidence of debugging to verify that)? That pointer being freed could be invalid due to a memory corruption or some other bug. Or it could have already been freed (that is a double free). Hence the suggestion to track all the allocated and freed pointer values or run valgrind. If you know how to debug then please go ahead and do some debugging and share what you find with us.

Comment: The address shown in the error output is unaligned so it is unlikely to be an address returned by `malloc`. Likely caused by this code: `over = malloc(sizeof(char) * READ_SIZE) + 1`. Have a careful look at that and see if you can spot why.

Comment: @kaylum Good spotting.

Comment: Thank you for your help, we'll take a deeper look at that.

Comment: Let us know if you don't work it out. And BTW, unrelated to the `free` problem but this line also appears to be wrong: `stock->save[stock->i] = over[stock->r];`. The memory for `over` was just freshly allocated and thus still uninitialised. It should not be read as its contents are undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an assignment for you, the best answer would be to have you look up how `free()` works in `C`.

[Standard C Free](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/)

Also, learn the difference between the stack and heap in `C`.  You're mixing them badly in your code.

[7. Memory : Stack vs Heap](http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html)

Answer (score -2):

First of all I am wondering why are you using `malloc()` instead of `calloc()`.
To find memory leak problems use [`Valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) tool. It is the best tool to find all the leaks.

Comment: How does use of `calloc` would help instead of `malloc`? There is no memory leak caused by `malloc` or `calloc`. Its this line `if ((over = malloc(sizeof(char) * READ_SIZE) + 1) == NULL)` which OP coded wrongly. Take a good look first

Comment: Mayukh you are right. There is no memory leak. But I suspect that root of cause memory leak. Apologize for miscommunication.